# How to return the today date into my DOMDocument - PHP

Tags: php

I´m collecting some data from a form as soon as the user click "submit" button. One of these data that I want to collect is the date when the form was submitted in the following format (d/m/Y).
I´m using the `echo date("d/m/Y")` to call the today date, however it´s not working.
Do I need to declare a function?  Or should I get the actual date from my submission data`s function?
Any clue?

**This is my actual code:**

```
function my_generate_xml($posted_data) 
{
    // build maximizer xml file
    $domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
    $domDocument->formatOutput = true;

    // moduledata root element
    $xml_root = $domDocument->createElement('moduledata');
    $domDocument->appendChild($xml_root);                          

    // entity element
    $xmlEntity = $domDocument->createElement('entity');
    $xml_root->appendChild($xmlEntity);    
    $xmlEntityTN = $domDocument->createAttribute('tablename');
    $xmlEntityTN->value = 'Ent';
    $xmlEntityFN = $domDocument->createAttribute('formatname');
    $xmlEntityFN->value = 'Curriculum';
    $xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlEntityTN);
    $xmlEntity->appendChild($xmlEntityFN);

    // data element
    $xml_data = $domDocument->createElement('Data');
    $xmlSiga->appendChild($xml_data);   

    // attribute child nodes
    $domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', echo date("d/m/Y"));
    $domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('domain');
    $domAttribute->value = 'Date';
    $domElement->appendChild($domAttribute);
    $xml_data->appendChild($domElement);                         

}
```

**Desired Output data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<moduledata>
  <entity tablename="Ent" formatname="Curriculum">
      <Data>
        <attribute domain="Date">14/07/2018</attribute>
      </Data>
  </entity>
</moduledata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `echo`. It's a function not returning anything, however, [`createElement()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) is waiting for a string as the second parameter.

```
 $domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', date("d/m/Y"));
```